Neovim JavaScript config
I'm trying to use null-ls with multiple sources for formatting and diagnostics in Neovim. Everything seems to be working fine when I run node file.js/file.ts from the terminal, but when I open the file in Neovim, I always get some issue (not specified in the question).
I've configured null-ls and lspconfig for several programming languages (JavaScript, TypeScript, Python, C++, Go, Shell scripts) as shown below, but the problem persists.
Configuration Files:
null-ls.lua:
return {
    {
        'jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim',
        event = "BufRead",
        dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' },
        config = function()
            local null_ls = require('null-ls')

            null_ls.setup({
                sources = {
                    -- JavaScript/TypeScript
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier.with({ command = "/opt/homebrew/bin/prettier" }), -- Specify Prettier path
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.eslint_d,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint_d,
                    null_ls.builtins.code_actions.eslint_d,

                    -- Python
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.black,
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.isort,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.flake8,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.mypy,

                    -- C/C++
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.clang_format,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.cppcheck,

                    -- Go
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.gofmt,
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.goimports,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.golangci_lint,

                    -- Shell scripts
                    null_ls.builtins.formatting.shfmt,
                    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.shellcheck
                },

                on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
                    if client.name == "null-ls" then
                        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, "formatexpr", "v:lua.vim.lsp.formatexpr()")
                    end
                end,

                settings = {
                    ["null-ls"] = {
                        setup = {
                            formatting = {
                                prettier = {
                                    tab_width = 2,
                                    single_quote = true,
                                    trailing_comma = "es5"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            -- Keymap for formatting with null-ls
            vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>gf', function() vim.lsp.buf.format() end, { noremap = true, silent = true })
        end
    }
}

lsp-config.lua:
return {
    {
        "williamboman/mason.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("mason").setup({
                ui = {
                    border = "rounded",
                    icons = {
                        package_installed = "✓",
                        package_pending = "➜",
                        package_uninstalled = "✗"
                    }
                }
            })
        end
    },
    {
        "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
                ensure_installed = {
                    "clangd",
                    "lua_ls",
                    "gopls",
                    "pyright",
                    "ts_ls" -- Use ts_ls instead of tsserver
                },
                automatic_installation = true
            })
        end
    },
    {
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        config = function()
            local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

            -- Global LSP settings
            vim.diagnostic.config({
                virtual_text = true,
                signs = true,
                update_in_insert = false,
                underline = true,
                severity_sort = true,
                float = {
                    border = 'rounded',
                    source = 'always'
                }
            })

            -- Grammarly specific setup with error handling
            local grammarly_ok, _ = pcall(function()
                lspconfig.grammarly.setup({
                    cmd = { "grammarly-languageserver", "--stdio" },
                    filetypes = {
                        "markdown",
                        "text",
                        "tex",
                        "latex"
                    },
                    root_dir = function()
                        return vim.loop.cwd()
                    end,
                    init_options = {
                        clientId = "client_BaDkMgx4X19X9UxxYRCXZo"
                    },
                    settings = {
                        grammarly = {
                            autoActivate = true,
                            suggestions = {
                                writing_style = "default",
                                dialect = "american"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            end)

            if not grammarly_ok then
                vim.notify("Failed to setup Grammarly LSP", vim.log.levels.ERROR)
            end

            -- Setup other LSP servers
            lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({})
            lspconfig.clangd.setup({})
            lspconfig.gopls.setup({})
            lspconfig.pyright.setup({})
            lspconfig.ts_ls.setup({})

            -- Key mappings
            vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, { desc = "Code Action" })
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, { desc = "Go to Definition" })
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, { desc = "Hover Information" })
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, { desc = "Go to Implementation" })
            vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, { desc = "Rename" })
        end
    }
}

I have made sure that all required binaries (Prettier, ESLint, etc.) are properly installed. I've also checked both null-ls and lspconfig configurations, but the issue still persists.
